# How to Exit out of a Python script without throwing an Error in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I uses a SQL Job which call the Python Script.. In some scenario I want to exit out of script without failing the job completely, but just by throwing some message. The SQL job has 3 steps such as 1. PreProcess 2. Process 3. PostProcess..
So In some situation, want to exit out of PreProcess but still want to process PostProcess.. Below is my class structure.

```
class Test:
   def pre_process():
      #some code
      sys.exit("exiting out of program")

   def process():
     #some code

   def post_process():
    #some code

  def run():
    try:
        pre_process()
        process()
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    finally:
        post_process()
```

So the issue here is the code is exiting out but with error. But want to exit out of the program successfully. Any suggestion is helpful!

Comment: Just use `sys.exit()` with no parameter.

Comment: This works. But I still want to pass some sort of message to the SQL Agent Job and how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
raise RuntimeError("Description of the error")
```

Something like this can be used.

You can also look into different loop breaking schemes of Python. Maybe this will be helpful: [How to break out of multiple loops in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python)