# Nested for loops, break

Tags: python

This seems quite simple but I can't get it to work. I'm using **Python 3**.

I have a nested for loop

```
for x in list:
    ch_id_dic[i]='channel_id'
    ch_id_dic2= dict((v,k) for k,v in ch_id_dic.items())
    for y in list_2:
        ch_id_dic[j]='description'
        ch_id_dic2= dict((v,k) for k,v in ch_id_dic.items())
        break
```

After the break statment it goes through the second element of list but then in the nested for loop it goes to the first element again. I want it to go to the second.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks...

Comment: It sounds like you want to iterate through both lists in lockstep.  Maybe using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function: `for x, y in zip(list1, list2)`

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't notice that the flag automatically made a comment. Thanks for feedback, Patrick.

Comment: Using the zip function worked! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of multiple loops in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python)

Comment: @BearBrown, if I understand it correctly, the goal is not to break out of both loops..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note that I have made this a CW post to mark it as answered. I take no credit for this answer and give it all to Patrick Haugh, who answered in comments.*

### Use `zip`.

You need to iterate through both lists at the same time. The `zip(list1,list2)` function takes two lists of equal size and turns them into a single list by doing something like `[(list1[index],list2[index]) for index in range(len(list1))]`.

Answer (score 0):

`break` statements end the current loop. In your case, as you noticed, it stops the nested loop and continues with the next iteration of the external loop.

It sounds like you are trying to keep the index of the outer loop to match the inner, so track the index of the outer loop with the `enumerate` function.

```
for idx, x in enuerate(list):
    ch_id_dic[i] = 'channel_id'
    ch_id_dic2 = dict((v,k) for k,v in ch_id_dic.items())
    for y in range(idx, len(list_2)):
        ch_id_dic[j] = 'description'
        ch_id_dic2 = dict((v,k) for k,v in ch_id_dic.items())
        break
```

If you need to use the old value of y at some point, just use `list_2[y]`.