# Python force block the loop operation (for)

Tags: python

i've this code, how to force the exit of for loop?:

```
    try:
            for i in list:
                    with open(i, 'r') as f:
                            json_data = json.load(f)
                    if something == some:
                            print("ddddddddddddddd")

                    else:
                            print("Check successful!!!")
    except IOError:
           print("exception")
```

i wuold block after print("dddddddd") how can i force the exit?

Comment: use `break` ?.....

Comment: Try to use `break`.

Comment: Yes, you can [break](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: Have you thought about using break?

Comment: `break` is the answer. This section of the docs explains in more detail: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of multiple loops in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python)

Comment: Have a `break`, have a KitKat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exit a `for` or `while` loop, use the keyword `break` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement)). This works for "infinite" loops too (like the one below).
Example:

```
n = 0
while True:
    print("Running")
    if n == 3:
        break
    n += 1
```

will print:

```
Running
Running
Running
Running
```

(since it'll run when `n` is `0`, `1`, `2` and `3` -> 4 times)