# Python lesson - broken code with Break command

Tags: python-3.x

This code is from a python lesson.  I'm not interested in breaking out of loops.  I need to understand what this code is actually doing - since I can't make it run.  The correct code is irrelevant.  I don't understand this code.  (The lesson results don't make sense.)

```
def find_512():
    for x in range(100):
        for y in range(100):
            if x * y == 512:
                 break   # does not do what we want!
    return f"{x} * {y} == 512"
```

Comment: are you looking for something like [breaking out of multiple for loops at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python)?

Comment: First lesson with Break.  According to lesson, it returns "99 * 99 =512"  I don't understand how the code generates that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of multiple loops in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python)

Comment: @LynnLCrawford, `break` causes the program to exit the loop within which you call it. In the lesson example, `break` is called in the inner `for loop` - that would leave the outer `for loop` running and calling the inner one again. Actually, it is not needed at all since you exit any loop within a function if you `return` something, see @UmeshChaudhary 's answer.

Comment: What part of the code are you having trouble to understand? The code should return ``'8 * 64 == 512'``, by the way.

Comment: Thank you @MrFuppes

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for first values of `x` and `y` then try this

```
def find_512():
  for x in range(100):
    for y in range(100):
      if x * y == 512:
        print('breaking')
        return f"{x} * {y} == 512"
```

If you want to break out from all the loops then this is the best solution.