# Break not working as expected inside python if statement for empty cells

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl, break

Cant figure out why the break is not working below:
Loaded the already existed excel file using openpyxl.

I tried printing the values before break, and it does print the row values that are empty. This confirms that the inside of loop is executed.

```
def x(ws):
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=11,max_row=50,min_col=4,max_col=4):
            for cell in row:
                if cell.value is None:
                    next_index=int(cell.row)
                    break

    print('The return is: ')
    print(next_index)


    return next_index
```

All I want is exit the loop with the first cell empty on that range but instead getting the last row i.e 50 return, where as expected return is 11.

Answer (score 1):

Your `break` statement will only break out of the inner `for` loop. Here's another relevant stackoverflow question: [How to break out of multiple loops in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python)

As suggested there you can just `return next_index` from the inner `for` loop instead of trying to break out of both loops to return the appropriate value.

Comment: oh! yeah it keeps looping for entire range because of multiple loops....thanks the return is the easiest way to fix and what I need :) cheers