# break command for nested loops inside conditional statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements, break

**I want to break main while loop using break statement inside if condition**

```
a = 0
b = True
while b:
    print(a)
    while a < 10:
        if a == 8:
            b = False
            break       # want to break both while loops using this command
        else:
            print(a)
            a += 1
```

result should be
0
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

Comment: please mention where you are stuck, we will be happy to help but can't write code for you

Comment: Check this out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn’t offer a way to break out of two (or more) loops at once, so the naive approach looks like this:

```
b = True
while b:
    print(a)
    while a < 10:
        if a == 8:
            b = False #Use this value to break out of top loop
            break
        else:
            print(a)
            a += 1
    if !b: #Use the value of b like this to break out of top loop
        break
```