# How can you go to the next word of a list on the previous loop in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, continue

To go to the next word in a loop you just need to use the continue function.

Ex.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for word in a:
    continue
```

But if the code is this:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for word in a:
    for word2 in word:
        continue
```

The continue function works for the second loop, but I want something that works for the first loop and at the same time written in the second loop.

Comment: What are you triying to do here ?

Comment: There's no continue function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to break out of multiple loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops)

Comment: Use `break` instead of `continue` there, that'll continue the outer loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break from the inner loop and use else to determine if the outer loop should continue.

```
a = ['aaaaxaaaa', 'bbbbbb', 'cccccxccc', 'ddddxddd']
for word in a:
    for letter in word:
        at_end=False
        if (letter == 'x'): break
        print(letter)
    else:    # only called at end of loop if no break
        at_end = True
    if (at_end == False): continue  # inner loop exited early
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the current index to help you navigate outside of the position of the loop. Enumerate builtin perfect for this.

```py
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
l = len(a)
for i, word in enumerate(a):
    nexti = i + 1
    nextword = a[nexti] if nexti <= l else None
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to determent if you need to continue the second time:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for word in a:
    for word2 in word:
        do_continue = true # Defining the variable
        continue
    if do_continue:
        continue
```

Comment: Looks like there is some typo in the code.