# Break out of two loops and two if statements - Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a section of code used to find a key value within a dictionary. The current method i'm using works, however i'm attempting to speed up the execution of the script.

To do this i want to move the `if ticker in tick:` to immediately after `for tick in trades_dic["Ticker"].items():`. The intention of which is to speed up this element by removing the need to check all combinations.

Full section of code below, any help would be much appreciated. :)

```
    for tick in trades_dic["Ticker"].items():
        for stat in trades_dic["Status"].items():
            if ticker in tick and "Open" in stat:
                (tick_k, tick_val) = tick
                (stat_k, stat_val) = stat
                if tick_k == stat_k:
                    (active_k, v) = tick
                    break
        else:
            continue
        break
```

Comment: make it function and use return statement if you want without break statement

Comment: Is `ticker` the key? Why are you looping instead of looking it up directly?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to break out of multiple loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189645/1324033)

Comment: @Sayse Just looking at the code, I'm pretty sure that's not the real question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `ticker` contains the key you're looking up in in both of your dictionaries -- looping over `items()` basically defeats the entire purpose of a dictionary structure. You can just look up the value directly by indexing with the key:

```
tick_val = trades_dic["Ticker"][ticker]
stat_val = trades_dic["Status"][ticker]
if stat_val == "Open":
    # do stuff with tick_val
```