# How to stop a while loop when there's a nested for loop inside?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, nested

I'm trying to create a `for loop` in a `while loop` and I need to break the outside `while loop` when `idx = 3`, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
arr = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
idx = 0

while idx < 3:
    for item in indices:
        arr[item] = idx
        idx += 1
        print('idx', idx)
```

Expected output:
`idx 1 idx 2 idx 3`

Actual output:
`idx 1 idx 2 idx 3 idx 4 idx 5`

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can had a condition in the second loop to  break if it is equal to 3

```
if idx == 3:
    break
```

edit:
but you can also follow this advice https://stackoverflow.com/a/189685/9936992

Comment: This worked. The while loop was unnecessary after adding it so I took it off and simply had the for loop and this statement

Comment: great then in your future question  try to give more detail about what you are trying to achieve with your code

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using break statement inside for:

```
while idx < 3:
    for item in indices:
        arr[item] = idx
        idx += 1
        print('idx', idx)
        if (idx >=3):
             break
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do:

```
arr = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
idx = 0

    while idx < 3:
        for item in indices:
            arr[item] = idx
            idx += 1
            print('idx', idx)
            if idx < 3:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Note that the actual output of your original code makes sense because `idx < 3` is checked before every iteration, but not within iterations. So once it was established that `idx` is indeed less than 3, the `for` loop takes place, and that will print and increase `idx` without checking its value. If you want `idx` to be checked and stop when reaches a certain point, you have to add the clause I added.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add an `if` statement in your `for` while and then pass a `break` statement in `if` block, like this:

```
arr = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
idx = 0

while idx < 3:
    for item in indices:
        arr[item] = idx
        idx += 1
        print('idx', idx)
        if idx == 3:
            break
```

Now when `idx` is equal to `3`, the loop will be terminated.

Have Fun :)