# Python - break statement not working in else statement within while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, break

The while loop in my code refuses to terminate when I use the break statement, and I'm really confused why this is happening.

```
point = 0
while point < len(list_of_line_lists) - 1:
    sentence = list_of_line_lists[point]["text"]
    datapoint = point
    while True:
        try:
            if list_of_line_lists[datapoint]["author"] == list_of_line_lists[datapoint + 1]["author"]:
                sentence += list_of_line_lists[datapoint + 1]["text"]
                datapoint += 1
                print(datapoint)
            else:
                print("this isn't breaking")
                break
        except IndexError:
            break
```

In my code above, the break statement within the else statement refuses to trigger. The code within it is executed, as there's a flurry of "this isn't breaking" in the output, but the loop itself doesn't terminate. This is how my output looks(until I manually stop it myself):

```
this isn't breaking
this isn't breaking
this isn't breaking
this isn't breaking
this isn't breaking
this isn't breaking
this isn't breaking
```

Any ideas to why this is happening?

Comment: You have two `while` loops, and the `break` will only exit the inner one. Have you put any any code at the end (or beginning) of the outer `while` loop to see if in fact the problem is there? Your outer loop is looking at the value of the `point` variable, and it doesn't look like you're ever changing that (or the `list_of_line_lists` variable inside your loop.

Comment: It breaks the inner loop but not the outer loop.

Comment: Okay, yeah that was a moronic mistake, I forgot to increment the point variable. I really am lacking sleep, and thanks a lot for the advice!
@larsks

Comment: see [How to break out of multiple loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop is breaking, but the outer loop isn't. The reason is because you are using the `point` variable in the outer while loop, but that (`point`) variable value is never changed (incremented/decremented).