# Why, despite fulfilling 'if' criterion, this break statement is not ending the loop?

Tags: python, break

I'm making a rock paper scissors game in python from a tutorial book. I think I'm following the book to the letter but for some reason this 'break' statement isn't working.

```
while True:  # Main game loop
    print('%s Wins, %s Losses, %s Ties' %(wins,losses,ties))
    while True: # Player input loop
        print('Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit')
        playerMove = input()
        if playerMove== 'q':
            sys.exit() # Quit the program
        if playerMove == 'r' or playerMove =='p' or playerMove =='s':
            print('at least this is working')
            break # Break out of player input loop
        print('but this is not')

        # Display player move
        if playerMove == 'r':
            print('ROCK versus...')
        elif playerMove == 'p':
```

The code goes on but this is all that is relevant for this problem. When I run it it shows up like this

```
ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS
0 Wins, 0 Losses, 0 Ties
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
r
at least this is working
0 Wins, 0 Losses, 0 Ties
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
```

The 'q' for quit option works just fine so it's clearly getting the input. Apart from that it just keeps repeating the loop.
As you can see I put some text in there just to experiment and show where things are breaking down.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you expect to break main game loop?

Comment: ``break`` only exits the closest loop, not all loops. It even says so in the comment of your code ``"break # Break out of player input loop"``

Answer (score 3):

The `break` statement will take you out of the innermost loop, not the "main" outer loop. Better change the inner loop to something like this:

```
input_loop = True
while input_loop: # Player input loop
    print('Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit')
    playerMove = input()
    if playerMove== 'q':
        sys.exit() # Quit the program
    if playerMove == 'r' or playerMove =='p' or playerMove =='s':
        print('at least this is working')
        input_loop = False # Break out of player input loop
    print('but this is not')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two nested loops. If you break out of the first one, you immediately re-enter it since you are not getting out of the second loop. I would instead change the first loop to instead of saying `while True`, say `while playing`, and set playing to False when game ends.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already told you, you have nested two loops. The `break` statement only gets you out of the inner loop, but you want to break out of the outer loop. A lot of answers on how to solve this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops).

Answer (score 0):

I have now resolved this,

initially the reason that

```
        print('but this is not')
```

did not print is because I had already broken that while loop.

The reason that the the code below did not run starting with the `# Display player move` section is because of the indentation. It, and the rest of the program is at the same indentation level as `# Player input loop` and so was disregarded once that loop was broken.

I moved the rest of the code over one indentation level and program works fine now