# How to break from multiple for loops at once in python

Tags: python

```
inc = 0
for i in range(100):
  for j in range(5):  
    print("before",inc)
    inc = inc + 1
    print("after",inc)
    if inc == 1:
      break
```

This is the minimum code. I want to break the all the loops at once and yes I do know a method that I found on this site
the method I found

```
inc = 0
done = None
for i in range(100):
  for j in range(5):  
    print("before",inc)
    inc = inc + 1
    print("after",inc)
    if inc == 1:
      done = True
      break
  if done:
    break
```

But the above method would be too long and tedious if there is a more than 4 loops or code is a bit more complex.
Is there a function/library that can help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to break out of multiple loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops)

Comment: wrap loops into a function and just `return` from it

Answer (score 1):

use else in the inner loop - If the inner for loop breaks the else will not be executed and the outer loop will break and vice-versa

```
inc = 0
for _ in range(100):
    for _ in range(5):  
        print("before",inc)
        inc += 1
        print("after",inc)
        if inc == 1:
            break
    else:
        continue 
    break
```