# How to break the loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am working on a project, where I need to exit the loop when  `already_exists` is True. I am not able to do so here. Or maybe I have put the loop wrongly.

```
loop = True

while loop is True:
    #loop for page numbers
    for page in range(1, 10):

        #prints page number on terminal
        print("Getting page {}..".format(page))

        #getting data from the website
        params["paged"] = page
        data = requests.post(url, data=params).json()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data["markup"], "html.parser")

        #loop to get the data from each entry (livewire-entry)
        for entry in soup.select(".livewire-entry"):

            datime = entry.select_one(".adate") #date&time ----- (1)
            status = entry.select_one(".status") #status ----- No conditions
            name = status.find_next("strong") #school ----- No conditions
            details = entry.select_one(".lw-details") #details ----- (2)


            datime = datime.get_text(strip=True)
            datime = datetime.datetime.strptime(datime, '%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p')
            time = str(datime.time()) #returns time
            date = str(datime.date()) #returns date


            already_exists = False
            for firstentry in csvFileArray:
                already_exists = (firstentry['Date'] == date
                             and firstentry['Time'] == time
                             and firstentry['Status'] == (status.get_text(strip=True))
                             and firstentry['School'] == name.get_text(strip=True)
                             and firstentry['Details'] == details.get_text(strip=True))

                if already_exists:
                    print('drop')
                    loop = False
                    break

            if not already_exists:
                print('updating...')
                writer.writerow(
                    [date, time, status.get_text(strip=True), name.get_text(strip=True), details.get_text(strip=True)])
```

Comment: The `break` statement only breaks out of the innermost loop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops

Comment: Actually you are not breaking the while loop

Comment: Just Indent back two lines

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ Still not working:/

Comment: Check with my answer

Comment: @Zoro How do I go about it without messing up w/ other loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below changes,

```
loop = True

while loop is True:
    #loop for page numbers
    for page in range(1, 10):

        #prints page number on terminal
        print("Getting page {}..".format(page))

        #getting data from the website
        params["paged"] = page
        data = requests.post(url, data=params).json()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data["markup"], "html.parser")

        #loop to get the data from each entry (livewire-entry)
        for entry in soup.select(".livewire-entry"):

            datime = entry.select_one(".adate") #date&time ----- (1)
            status = entry.select_one(".status") #status ----- No conditions
            name = status.find_next("strong") #school ----- No conditions
            details = entry.select_one(".lw-details") #details ----- (2)


            datime = datime.get_text(strip=True)
            datime = datetime.datetime.strptime(datime, '%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p')
            time = str(datime.time()) #returns time
            date = str(datime.date()) #returns date


            already_exists = False
            for firstentry in csvFileArray:
                already_exists = (firstentry['Date'] == date
                             and firstentry['Time'] == time
                             and firstentry['Status'] == (status.get_text(strip=True))
                             and firstentry['School'] == name.get_text(strip=True)
                             and firstentry['Details'] == details.get_text(strip=True))
            # Changes here Indentation
            if already_exists:
                print('drop')
                loop = False
                break

            if not already_exists:
                print('updating...')
                writer.writerow(
                    [date, time, status.get_text(strip=True), name.get_text(strip=True), details.get_text(strip=True)])
```

Comment: loops infinitely, plus, gets a problem with csv file

Comment: Yes that probably doesn't satisfy the condition

Comment: The best practice is that use custom functions for validations or condition checking so it will be easy to debug :)

Comment: added 
```   #loop for page numbers
    for page in range(1, 10):
        if not loop:
          break
``` at the start of loop and worked