# How to exit a nested for loop in Robot Framework 4.0 in ride 1.7.4.2

Tags: robotframework, nested-for-loop

I wanna exit all nested for loops when ${port} == 3,however whatever keywords I use, such as
'Exit for loop' or 'Exit for loop  if ${port} == 3' ,it will still continue the whole nested for loop. Meanwhile Robot Framework ride tells me that 'break' is a reserved keyword and can't be used.
My code is below.

```
*** Test Cases ***
demo_01
    ${port}    Set Variable    0
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    2
FOR    ${j}    IN RANGE    2
FOR    ${k}    IN RANGE    2
    ${port}    Evaluate    ${port} + 1
    Log    ${port}
    IF    ${port} == 3
    Exit FOR Loop
END
END
END
END
```

And the result is here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdCaz.png)

It just exited the inner for loop. :(

So I wanna know how to exit a nested  for loop in Robot Framework Ride. Thank you all.
BTW here is my pip list below

```
robotframework                  4.1.2
robotframework-databaselibrary  1.2.4
robotframework-pythonlibcore    3.0.0
robotframework-ride             1.7.4.2
robotframework-selenium2library 3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary  3.0.0
robotframework-sshlibrary       3.8.0
```

And my python version is

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -V
Python 3.7.9
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this is to move the enclosing FOR loops into a keyword and then return from it whenever a condition is met. In your case it will look like this:

```
*** Keywords ***
Log ports
    [Return]    Return when port 3 is reached

    ${port}    Set Variable    0
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    2
        FOR    ${j}    IN RANGE    2
            FOR    ${k}    IN RANGE    2
                ${port}    Evaluate    ${port} + 1
                Log    ${port}
                IF    ${port} == 3
                    Return From Keyword
                END
            END
        END
    END
```

Then in the test you just call the above keyword:

```
*** Test Cases ***
demo_01
    Log ports
```

Comment: yeah thank you. You provide me with a new solution to my testcase. Though I'm wondering is there a way to exit nested for loops without moving these loops in keywords. It's OK if you tell me there is none, I'm just curious. Thanks again.

Comment: From what I know there is no other clean solution to break from multiple nested loops. You can have a look at this topic for python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops as some solutions from there can be ported to Robot Framework. From all of them the return / Return From Keyword seem to be the best.