# How to stop the execution of all loops on break instruction

Tags: python, loops

I have to execute a for loop to traverse a list that resides inside a `while` loop like the following example:

```
while True:
    for i in range(0, 100):
        if i > 50:
            break
    print(i)
```

The problem I'm facing right now is that `break` instruction only stops the execution of the `for` loop, leaving the infinite `while True` always reach the `print(i)` line. So my question is, how can I add an instruction like `break` to close both while and for loops? And if there would be more than 2 nested loops, how could this be done?

The output of the last example is:

```
51
51
51
51
51
51
51
51
51
51
...
```

The desired functioning of the `"break"` line would lead to a null input for that example, which is the correct solution the code should give. The main goal here is to substitute `break` with an appropriate instruction to perform loop exiting.

Comment: Put it in a function and use `return`?

Comment: @guy I thought about this solution but the return of my function can't be instead of break, because it has to perform more computations

Comment: You will completely lose control over your code if you try to exit an arbitrary amount of loops at once.

Comment: @Cardstdani Then make those computations. You can create multiple functions, you know.

Comment: Throw an exception? Delete the `while True:`? I suspect this might be an AB issue, though.

Comment: @matszwecja, I'd say it sometimes is a good idea to exit more than one loops. Depends on situation.

Comment: @KenY-N [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), you mean?

Comment: @Cardstdani It's so sad that the question is closed.I think `for... else...`  its a good idea.  
If not break in `for`, it will execute `break` in else
```
while True:
    for i in range(0, 100):
        if i > 50:
            break
    else:
        break
    print("I > 50")
    break

```

Comment: The question has been raised zillion of times, here and elsewhere. It has even been formalized as a PEP, but it was [rejected](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-July/008663.html) by GvR for both technical and "code average quality" reasons

Comment: @CN-LanBao The [second answer on the dup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150107/1270789) suggests the `for...else` construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a variable for that. Like this

```py
run = True
while run:
    for i in range(0, 100):
        if i > 50:
            run = False
            break
    print(i)
```

--- EDIT ---

Even if above works, the highest ranked solution on [How can I break out of multiple loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-can-i-break-out-of-multiple-loops) is more elegant.

```py
while True:
    for i in range(0, 100):
        if i > 50:
            break
    else:
       continue
    print(i)
    break
```