# Index of the first duplicate element

Tags: python

I need help with finding the index of the first duplicate element in array.
I tried this but it gets me all indices of all duplicate elements.

```
res = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(input) if item in input[:idx]]
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem with code

Comment: @CarlHR Eliminating duplicates and finding the index of the first duplicate are related, but not the same.

Comment: Sidenote: you're shadowing `input`. Once you define your own variable named that, you lose access to Python's builtin `input` (and could potentially encounter confusing bugs if you try to use it).

Comment: When saying „the first duplicate element“ are you referring to the first duplicate for a specific number or for all different numbers that have duplicates in the array?.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately your idea is *O(n^2)*, because slicing and checking membership is *O(n)* and you do this within a loop. It's essentially a nested loop.

Instead, you can do this in *O(n)* using a single loop:

```
seen = {}
for i, item in enumerate(my_input):
    if item in seen:
        break
    seen[item] = i
else:
    i = item = None
```

At the end of the loop, `item` is the first duplicate item and `i` is its index. `seen[item]` will hold the index of the *first* occurrence of this duplicate item.

Comment: You can use a set instead: return the first index of something already in it

Comment: I added a couple of implementations

Comment: @MadPhysicist The [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74059349/1) used a set.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: use [wim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74059349/12975140) or [Mad Physicist's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74059939/12975140) answers. Anything based on the technique you're starting with will do a lot of unnecessary looping. The following isn't so much a *solution* as some parallel ideas about how your current code could be improved.

The *simplest* modification to your code would be to simply access the *first* item of the resulting list:

```
res = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(values) if item in values[:idx]][0]
```

But that's kind of silly, since you'll still be traversing the entire list, finding all duplicates, then throwing away all but one. It will also throw a `KeyError` if the list is empty (that is, if there are no duplicates). A cleaner and more efficient method would be to call [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on a version of your list comprehension turned into a [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehensions):

```
res = next((idx for idx, item in enumerate(values) if item in values[:idx]), None)
```

`None` is supplied as a default which will be returned if no duplicates are found.

This still has the same efficiency issues that wim points out, but knowing about indexing, `next`, and generator expressions can be useful!

Comment: I figured out how to do it in O(N) if you're willing to initialize a set on a separate line

Comment: I usually try to avoid side effects  and `or` tricks like that because I come back in a month and have to puzzle out what I did, but that's clever!

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a set of items you've seen so far:

```
def first_dup(a):
    seen = set()
    for i, e in enumerate(a):
        if e in seen:
            return i
        seen.add(e)
    return -1
```

You can isolate the `set` check into a separate function and combine the rest into an efficient one-liner using `next`:

```
def first_dup(a):
    seen = set()
    return next((i for i, e in enumerate(a) if (e in seen or seen.add(e))), -1)
```

This cheats by using the fact that `or` will evaluate the second expression any time the first is False, and `set.add` is an in-place operation that returns None.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first index in the iteration:

```
array=[2,3,4,5,3]
for i,a in enumerate(array):
    for j in range(i):
        if a==array[j]:
            print(j)
            exit()
```

If you want the last index in the iteration:

```
array=[2,3,4,5,3]
for i,a in enumerate(array):
    for j in range(i):
        if a==array[j]:
            print(i)
            exit()
```

Comment: This is also _O(n^2)_, suboptimal.

Comment: Why use `exit()` rather than breaking out of the loop?

Comment: Because I wanted to exit all loops at once and I had no problem with closing the program. If you want, you can use breaks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150107/15123109