# Create a new context manager instance every X iterations

Tags: python, loops

Say that I have a context manager, CM, that creates a new API session. How can I create a new context manager every 10 iterations of using it? The issue is that the API can only handle so many requests.

```
counter = 0
# <some loop make new session when counter reaches 10> 
with new_session() as session:
   # Do stuff 
   counter += 1
```

My first thought was to do something like `if counter % 10 == 0: make new session` but that doesn’t preserve the session for the whole 10 iterations.

I can’t figure out how to set up the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop for 10 iterations *inside* the context manager.

Then you can put the whole thing in another loop to keep going for multiples of 10 iterations.

```
keep_going = True

while keep_going:
    with new_session() as session:
        for _ in range(10):
            # do stuff
```

To stop, set `keep_going` to `False` at some point.

If you need more fine-grained control over when to stop, you could put everything inside a function and use a `return` statement to exit (see [How can I break out of multiple loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-can-i-break-out-of-multiple-loops)).